# issue with event Bubbling in js

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
#a {background-color:blue;width:100px;height:200px;}
#b {background-color:red;margin-left:25px;width:50px;height:100px;}
</style> 
<div id="a">a
    <div id="b">b</div> 
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function() {console.log("A is clicked");} 
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function(event) {console.log("B is clicked");event.stopPropagation();} 
document.onclick = function() {console.log("Document is clicked");} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Questions:

1.`function(event)`, `event` is formal parameter, what is the actual parameter? how did actual parameter pass to event? Because usually we use parameters in below style:

```
function method(int num){ //num is the formal
/*implementation*/
}

//in main
method(42); //42 is the actual
```

1. when I clicked div a, in console, it shows:

> ```
> A is clicked
> Document is clicked
> ```

I thought the result should be

> A is clicked
>    B is clicked

this is my thought: when clicked div a, `document.getElementById("a").onclick` got excuted, then `document.getElementById("b").onclick` got excuted, since we have `event.stopPropagation();` it will stop in div b, and will not excute `document.onclick`, but it seems not work this way, can anyone help me to understand what happened here?

Comment: An excellent [Quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) about events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `function(event)`, `event` is formal parameter, what is the actual parameter?

The actual parameter is an event object, created by the browser. For a click event, it will be an instance of [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent).

> when I clicked div a... I thought the result should be...

You clicked on the *parent* of `b`. The event propagates *up the DOM tree* from the target, so it will never touch `b`. The propagation phase will start at `a`, and move up through each parent until it reaches the document.

Had you clicked on `b`, the `stopPropagation` method would have prevented the event from bubbling and you would only see "B is clicked" in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Event propagation means bubling up of event in to the ancestor chain till the document object.

So in your case both event attached to element a and document are fired. When you click on element b then event attached to only element b is fired since the propagation is prevented from that point onward.

Answer (score 0):

The `event` is the browser event. You cannot really change it, but you can use closures or use data attributes to pass more data into your event handler.
You got the right result on clicking A. The event bubbles upwards to until it reaches the document's root element. If you stop propagation, you prevent it from bubbling upwards to it's parent elements.
If you click `b` then it would bubble upwards to `a` then to the `body`. But you stop propagation on `b` so the only output should be

```
B is clicked
```

The `event` object itself is different in every browser, although there is a [recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-Event) for it. Some browsers don't support the `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` methods or other properties (for example older IEs don't fully support the DOM Level 2 specs).